# Two weeks' overdue

Tags: apostrophe

I was reading an IELTS model response from the British Council and I saw this:

> Congratulations! Your little bundle of joy has arrived at last! I had heard from our friend Christie that you were two week**s'** overdue.

Why "two week**s'** overdue"?

I googled this and on the first page , correct me if i'm wrong , all of the links showed "two weeks overdue".

Why do we have this apostrophe? Is this a mistake?

Comment: No, looks like an error to me...

Comment: I agree that it's an error - a case of hypercorrection. Many English speaker are unsure about the apostrophe in sentences like *in three weeks' time*. When they learn to put it in, they overapply the rule and end up putting apostrophes where they don't belong. It's the same thing you see in *would you guys like to come for dinner with Maisie and I?*.

Comment: an error - there's no contraction or possession here.

Answer (score 2):

In short: *two weeks' overdue* is uncommon at best, and a mistake at worst. Most people would consider it a mistake.

A longer analysis follows.

---

This is not *necessarily* a mistake. Arguably, it's a matter of style—and different style guides may give different guidance. (Although I've yet to see one that gives guidance in favour of this *specific* construction.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Time_periods):

> Time periods are sometimes put into possessive form, to express the duration of or time associated with the modified noun:
>
> *the Hundred Years' War*
>         *a day's pay*
>         *two weeks' notice*

[The University of Calgary](https://english.ucalgary.ca/grammar/course/punctuation/3_7.htm):

> ***Use the apostrophe in phrases of time or measurement.***
>
> Examples: seven o'clock     a month's leave     my money's worth

[Grammar and Style in British English: A Comprehensive Guide for Students, Writers and Academics](https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-the-apostrophe.html#apostrophe:%20space%20and%20time):

> The possessive apostrophe is also used for measurements of time –
>
> **a week’s time**
>         **two weeks’ time**
>         **six months’ jail**
>         **twenty years’ service**

[Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/apostrophes_in_time_(temporal)_expressions.htm):

> Apostrophes are used in time expressions (e.g., *three years' experience, two days' pay, one day's time*). These are also known as *temporal expressions*.

---

Having said that, note that there is a syntactic difference between all of the style guide examples above and the actual phrase in the question itself.

In the style guide examples, the possessives are used with *nouns*. However, the question's phrase is *adjectival*. So, can we use a possessive form with adjectival time-based phrases specifically?

The Grammar Monster reference above says that apostrophes are used in temporal expressions. According to [*Temporal Expressions*](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/workbench/update/guides/03%20-%20Temporal%20Expressions_v2.0.1.pdf) (PDF), from the MIT Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence Lab:

> When  marked,  the  full  extent  of  a  temporal  expression  must  be  one  of  noun (4),  noun phrase (5), adjective (6), adjectival phrase (7), adverb (8), or adverbial phrase (9).

Unfortunately, while that paper shows that a time expression can be adjectival, it doesn't give an example of the possessive being used.

---

Turning to Google Books Ngram Viewer, I ran [a query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weeks%27+time%2Cweeks+time%2Cweeks+overdue%2Cweeks%27+overdue%2C+weeks%27+late%2C+weeks+late&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweeks%20%27%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20overdue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20%27%20late%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20late%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cweeks%20'%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20overdue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20'%20late%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeks%20late%3B%2Cc0) with the following search term: *weeks' time,weeks time,weeks overdue,weeks' overdue,weeks' late,weeks late*.

[image: time expressions]

From this:

- The most common time expression (noun) is *weeks' time*, with an apostrophe.
- The expression *weeks' overdue* (adjective), doesn't appear at all.
- The expression *weeks' late* (adjective) *does* appear, albeit with far less frequency than *weeks late*.)

What I would take away from this is that, barring a style guide that says something specifically different about the *adjectival* use of time expressions, the predominantly common styling is to omit the apostrophe from the phrase in question.

As such, *two weeks' overdue* may, arguably, not be a theoretical mistake—but it certainly looks like a practical mistake.

---

There is also a grammatical analysis that indicates the possessive with an adjectival phrase (or at least the one in the question) is actually wrong.

The possessive is a shortened version of the preposition ***of***:

> a day's pay
>   → ✔ a pay ***of*** a day.
>
> a week's time
>   → ✔ a time ***of*** a week

But we can't use a similar substitution with the following:

> two week's overdue
>   → ✘ overdue ***of*** a week

If we were to use a preposition, it would be *by*—but the apostrophe doesn't represent that.